# Does it have an impact on the game whether I check "Investigate" options or not?

Tags: mass-effect

I played through Mass Effect in the past and I know what dialogues a lot of the "Investigate" options hold in conversations.

I was wondering whether they have an impact on the future dialogue options or on the story or not? Does it change the game in any way if I click them all or it is just flavour text like in Still Life?

Comment: My guess so far is that it does not change anything if you click all the options but I'm still not sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first two games of Mass Effect I did almost all the investigation options and never saw a paragon/renegade choice. I've only played the first one through once and the second one through twice, but I reached full renegade without any investigation on my second playthrough of ME2.

I think there were some paragon/renegade investigation options in the third game.

Answer (score -2):

**Yes**.

In fact,

> In order to unlock the paragon or renegade option to convince Saren (in 1) and The Illusive Man (in 3) to shoot themselves during the final confrontation, you need to have chosen all paragon or renegade (all of the same alignment) with each prior convo, and some of them are behind 'Investigate' branches.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this question refers to the first game in the series, based on the tag, so this doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: I think the Paragorn/Renegade options are *not* the same as the "Investigate" options.

Comment: Can you name an exact situation when one of these conversation options was behind an "Investigate" branch?

Comment: Off the top of my head, either the first or second conversation with TIM in 3, as well as the penultimate one after you've passed the point of no return.

Comment: Who does the abbreviation TIM stand for?

Comment: @edem The Illusive Man. He's a character in Mass Effect 2 and 3.

Comment: Ah, I get it. I played through all games and for example at the end of ME1 I was able to "redeem" Saren, but not TIM at the end of ME3.

Comment: So it seems that only key caracter "Investigate" options have to be unrolled?

Comment: Technically you don't "have to" unroll any of them; it's just that sometimes (read: not often enough) they lead to something you can use later.

Comment: Bear in mind, even if there's no *mechanical* use for the answers, a lot of it tends to be fairly interesting information about the 'verse...